# "Transport failed" trying to access iPhone filesystem using iFuse

Tags: iphone

I want to access iPhone file system using CLI form Ubuntu 12.10 
I have installed ifuse. But it gives me the error Transport failed. How to solve?

Comment: Question: Is this iPhone jailbroken?

Comment: Yes, it is jailbroken